# netstat/net-tools package not found on RHEL

Tags: linux, redhat, netstat

I can't install netstat on my redhat server, I can't even find which packet provides it, and when I go through net-tools package installation I can't find the net-tools package as well.
Bellow is what I tried

```
[root@njwvms04 ~]# netstat -a
-bash: netstat : commande introuvable

[root@njwvms04 ~]# yum install netstat
Modules complémentaires chargés : enabled_repos_upload, imgbased-persist, package_upload, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager, vdsmupgrade, versionlock
Excluding 92 updates due to versionlock (use "yum versionlock status" to show them)
Aucun paquet netstat disponible.
Erreur : Rien à faire
Uploading Enabled Repositories Report
Modules complémentaires chargés : product-id, subscription-manager, versionlock
Unable to upload Enabled Repositories Report

[root@njwvms04 ~]# yum whatprovides */netstat
Modules complémentaires chargés : enabled_repos_upload, imgbased-persist, package_upload, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager, vdsmupgrade, versionlock
Excluding 92 updates due to versionlock (use "yum versionlock status" to show them)
No matches found
Uploading Enabled Repositories Report
Modules complémentaires chargés : product-id, subscription-manager, versionlock
Unable to upload Enabled Repositories Report

[root@njwvms04 ~]# yum install net-tools
Modules complémentaires chargés : enabled_repos_upload, imgbased-persist, package_upload, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager, vdsmupgrade, versionlock
centos-opstools-release                                                                                                                                                              | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
centos-sclo-rh-release                                                                                                                                                               | 3.0 kB  00:00:00     
ovirt-4.1-centos-qemu-ev                                                                                                                                                             | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
ovirt-4.1-epel/x86_64/metalink                                                                                                                                                       |  17 kB  00:00:00     
ovirt-4.1-patternfly1-noarch-epel                                                                                                                                                    | 3.0 kB  00:00:00     
ovirt-4.2-centos-gluster312                                                                                                                                                          | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
ovirt-4.2-centos-opstools                                                                                                                                                            | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
ovirt-4.2-centos-ovirt42                                                                                                                                                             | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
ovirt-4.2-centos-qemu-ev                                                                                                                                                             | 2.9 kB  00:00:00     
ovirt-4.2-epel/x86_64/metalink                                                                                                                                                       |  17 kB  00:00:00     
ovirt-4.2-virtio-win-latest                                                                                                                                                          | 3.0 kB  00:00:00     
sac-gdeploy                                                                                                                                                                          | 3.0 kB  00:00:00     
virtio-win-stable                                                                                                                                                                    | 3.0 kB  00:00:00     
Excluding 92 updates due to versionlock (use "yum versionlock status" to show them)
Aucun paquet net-tools disponible.
Erreur : Rien à faire
Uploading Enabled Repositories Report
Modules complémentaires chargés : product-id, subscription-manager, versionlock
Unable to upload Enabled Repositories Report
```

Here is my distribution configuration :

```
[root@njwvms04 ~]# cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
VERSION="7.7"
VERSION_ID="7.7"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VARIANT="Red Hat Virtualization Host"
VARIANT_ID="ovirt-node"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Virtualization Host 4.3.7 (el7.7)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.7:GA:hypervisor"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"

# FIXME
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Virtualization"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.7
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Virtualization"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.7
```

Answer (score 1):

What i think is all of the repositories you have enabled might not have the package net-tools, so use all centos global repositories and enable them, then run the commands

```
# yum -y install epel-release
# yum clean all
# yum update all
# yum install -y net-tools
```

This will only work if you epel repository is configures properly.